# Problem while uploading code in arduino atmega2560

Tags: c, arduino

I have arduino atmega2560 when i upload blink code than it shows error

```
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout.
```

I have checked the COM port is correct also that the driver is correctly installed.
Why would I be receiving a `timeout` error?

Comment: Perhaps ask this on arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please give more info and the upload log.

Comment: Check that you have set the right port and board.

Comment: Thanks all for your comment. COM port is right @thebusybee.any other solution..?any littel help can be appreciated.

Comment: What about the board? I don't have the Arduino IDE installed here but I remember that there are several choices including different protocols.

Comment: Board is atmega2560 selected.

Comment: Did this Arduino work before? When it doesn't have the bootloader or got it overwritten or is damaged in another way, the transfer will also not work. If you have another Arduino you can use that as a "burning device" if I remember correctly. And the IDE should have a menu command for this.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reasons:

1. Faulty communication cable
2. Wrong com port selected
3. Wrong device model selected
4. Baud rate settings
5. Driver related issues

Answer (score -1):

I think your arduino got bricked. But first try to reconnect it and upload your program.
Second try to disconnect any rx or tx pin connected. Third if your arduino is bricked, try to check this article for full solution of bricked arduino. [Programmer is not responding arduino](https://www.sheebot.com/2019/07/sketch-not-uploading-through-usb.html)